# Outlook App for Office task pane

Tags: c#, outlook, office365-apps, apps-for-office, outlook-web-addins

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am trying to create an App for Office for Outlook. I would like to create a task pane but there is no option to select Outlook when creating a task pane app. Creating a mail app places the app within the mail item.

I know that it is possible using VSTO however I want to use Apps for Office as it better suits the requirements in terms of deployment.

So is it actually possible to create an App for Office for Outlook that is a task pane located on the side?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt267546.aspx

However they are a little different from the custom panes that are contextual or based on activation rules as they must be launched from your custom Ribbon button. They also currently work only in the Outlook 2016 client and not in OWA or Outlook.com.

Comment: Interesting! One of the reasons we decided on Apps for Office though is because we could create 1 App that would work across all of the different clients... 

Is it currently possible to make that happen?

Comment: Yes, that is the intent. However, some features get introduced only to the desktop clients first and are later implemented for the web versions. Keep your eyes on https://dev.office.com/ for announcements